# Javascript for fetching the contents of an web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fetch the value of class `.cell-hover` through javascript and it should print the value which is present in double quotes. So far I tried:

```
var phonenumbers = document.getElementsByClassName('cell-hover');
document.write(phonenumbers);
```

but its printing `[object HTMLCollection]`, and I want to print the exact value.

Attached Snapshot:

[image: Console Log Screenshot]

Comment: try `console.log( phonenumbers[0] .innerHTML)`

Comment: do you have a link to your live site?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('cell-hover');` will return an array  of elements with class name `cell-hover`.Loop through that and print the result.For the content inside that class use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). The innerHTML will return DOM content as a String

You can also use `node.textContent;`  if you know that your div contains only text 
Here in the snippet i have printed the content of the first element with class name `cell-hover`

```js
var phonenumbers = document.getElementsByClassName('cell-hover');
 
document.write( phonenumbers[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="cell-hover">
 2637145689
</div>
```

```js
 var phonenumbers = document.getElementsByClassName('cell-hover');
     
     for(var i=0; i < phonenumbers.length ; i++){
         document.write( phonenumbers[0].textContent );
     }
```

```html
<div class="cell-hover">
     2637145689
</div>
```

Comment: @AkshayPatil try console.log( phonenumbers )

Comment: @AkshayPatil Have  you checked the console what it is printing there??.It should work if you have a class with name `cell-hover` in DOM .Check my snippet.if not check your console what `console.log( phonenumbers )` is printing

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
document.write(document.querySelector('.cell-hover').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.write(document.querySelector('.cell-hover').innerText);`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.